# Strongly Typed Resources Causing Problems?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, .net-2.0, resources

In the middle of some refactoring and I've moved a resources file from one project to another. I think I clicked a warning telling me to Strongly type the resource file at one point and now I'm getting:

> Could not find any resources
>   appropriate for the specified culture
>   or the neutral culture.  Make sure
>   "MyProject.Common.ResourceManagement.resources"
>   was correctly embedded or linked into
>   assembly "MyProject.Common" at compile
>   time, or that all the satellite
>   assemblies required are loadable and
>   fully signed.

Which is from a MissingManifestResourceException I beleive.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.missingmanifestresourceexception.aspx

I've looked up a couple of the solutions:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/ngur/archive/2003/12/28/46219.aspx
- http://jameswho.blogspot.com/2004/06/missingmanifestresourceexception.html
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318603

But none of them seem relevant to my situation.

Any ideas? This has been bugging me for a few days now.

Am I doing something stupid?

Comment: What was your plan with the refactoring? Creating a common resource DLL with public resources to be referred to by other projects in your solution?

Comment: No, this has just happened as a side effect. A lot of the classes that used the resources file had moved into the Common project so I figured it made more sense there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure these resource files are embedded into the assembly? Maybe you've lost the "Embedded Resource" settings as you moved the files.
Further, the resource names may have changed. The fully qualified name of a resource is
AssemblyName + physical subfolder(s) + resource name

Comment: If I could I'd up this answer 1 million times I would.  You brought hours of misery to an end.

Note sure how my resource was changed from "Embedded Resource" to "Content" but this was indeed the problem.

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Can you export them to a text file from the original project and import them into the new project?  If it's just key/value pairs it should be simple.